# Not able to open Facebook Messages in Android Webview

Tags: android, facebook, webview, messenger

This is how I am initializing my Web View

```
    webview1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview1.loadUrl("https://www.facebook.com/raquel.corpusescalante");
    webview1.setWebViewClient(new WebClientClass());
    webview1.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

This is WebClientClass

```
public class WebClientClass extends WebViewClient {
    ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(WebViewGeneralActivity.this);

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        if (pd != null && !pd.isShowing()) {
            pd.setTitle("Por favor espera");
            pd.setMessage("Cargando...");
            pd.show();
        }

    }
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        pd.dismiss();
    }
}
```

This facebook profile page loads completely but when i click on message icon it shows me error
[image]

What could be the reason for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually it tries to open facebook messenger in web view for which it sends an intent link in the webview i.e. intent:// user .... so i handled it by changing code like

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
   if(!(url.startsWith("intent"))){
    view.loadUrl(url);
   }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Super Perfect 100% working answer and source code. Thanks

Comment: Any idea how to do the same in Flutter/Dart?